# Xamarin + RestSharp request returning empty JSON

Tags: xamarin, flask, getjson, restsharp

I'm trying to get JSON from Flask-RESTful API but instead of:

```
  [
   [
    {
      "c_t": [],
      "imie": "test",
      "login": "test2",
      "nazwisko": "test3",
      "oferty": [],
      "password": "passpass",
      "user_id": 13,
      "u_t": []
    }
  ],
  {}
]
```

I'm getting empty string as response.Content. Here is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://SERVER-IP");
var request = new RestRequest("/users", Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
 RunOnUiThread(delegate
 {
    var responseC = response.Content;

    Toast.MakeText(this, responseC, Toast.Length.Long).Show();
 });
});
```

Comment: When doing the request from a browser "https://SERVER-IP/users", what are you receiving?

Comment: I'm getting proper json.

Comment: You are running this on the simulator? Try accessing the "https://SERVER-IP//users" from the simulator/device browser. Also remember to set your internet permissions.

Comment: So we launch this method from browser and it's work like a charm, the output looks like this json printed in topic. Problem is only on mobile platform, the output is just empty. We have a permissions in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **http** instead of **https** ;) This is what fixed it for us.